# differential for a changing log base

Tags: differential

I can't find a formula for when the actual base of a $\log$ changes. I specifically mean this scenario.

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\log_{a + h}[b] - \log_{a}[b]}{h} 
$$

The reason why I need it is that I am using an alternate notation that makes this problem obvious.  Use up arrow for a power, and down arrow for $\log$.

$$
  \underbrace{a \downarrow (b \uparrow c)}_{\log_a[b^c]} = \underbrace{(a \downarrow b)\ c}_{c\ \log_a[b]}  
$$

In this alternate notation, this is $a^b$ implicitly differentiated.  It is it handles both $a$ and $b$ changing at the same time.

$$
  d[a + b] = d[a] + d[b]
$$

$$
  d[a * b] = b\ d[a] + a\ d[b]
$$

$$
  d[a \uparrow b] = (a \uparrow b) ( \frac{b}{a} d[a] + \underbrace{(e \downarrow a)}_{ln[a]} d[b]) 
$$

$d[a \uparrow b]$ in more familiar notation looks like:

$$
  d[a^b] = b\ a^{b-1} d[a] + a^b ln[a]\ d[b]
$$

But this leaves the question of how to then define $d[a \downarrow b]$.  It needs to handle the case where $a$ is not a constant, because this is a non-commutative and non-associative binary operator.  I can't find anything anywhere that handles a changing base. I don't know what goes in place at the big star.

$$
  d[a \downarrow b] = \bigstar d[a] + \frac{1}{b (e \downarrow a)}d[b]
$$

What I did try was to just use change of base formula to get something like:

$$
  (a + \delta a) \downarrow (b + \delta b) = \frac{e \downarrow (b + \delta b)}{e \downarrow (a + \delta a)} = \frac{\ln[b] + \ln[1 + \frac{\delta b}{b}]}{\ln[a] + \ln[1 + \frac{\delta a}{a}]}
$$

Which doesn't look right, because I am expecting that when $\delta a = 0$, I get the normal formula for differential of $\log$ function.

Comment: I didn't really quite understand actually, but from the first formula I guess you're trying to calculate $\frac{d\log_x(b)}{dx}$

Comment: yes, implicitly differentiating $log_x[b]$ to be specific, where my notation would be $d[x \downarrow b]$, and both x and b are variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ordinary differentiation rules we get
$$(\log_xb)'=\left(\frac{\ln b}{\ln x}\right)'=-\frac{\ln b}{x(\ln x)^2}=-\frac{\log_xb}{x\ln x}$$
which in your notation is
$$-\frac{x\downarrow b}{x(e\downarrow x)}$$

Comment: I'm going to assume that the answer to this question is:  $d[a \downarrow b] = -\frac{a \downarrow b}{a(e \downarrow a)}\ d[a] + \frac{1}{b(e \downarrow a)}\ d[b]$.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle y = \log_x z $

or, $\displaystyle x^y = z $

or, $\displaystyle y \ln x = \ln z$

or, $\displaystyle dy ~ \ln x + y \frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dz}{z}$

or, $\displaystyle dz = z \ln x ~ dy + \frac{yz}{x} ~ dx$

or, $\displaystyle dz = x^y \ln x ~ dy + yx^{y-1} ~ dx $

Probably you are looking for the above result, right?